# AttributeError: Cannot import 'lmdb', therefore 'LMDBSerializer' is not available

Tags: python, pytorch, dataflow, lmdb

i'm using tensorpack and lmdb the first time and getting this error:
AttributeError: Cannot import 'lmdb', therefore 'LMDBSerializer' is not available

Unfortunately, I can't find much about it googling it. I installed lmdb 0.97 and tensorpack 0.9.8.

```
from tensorpack import dataflow

ds = []
for data in datafile:
    ds.append(dataflow.LMDBSerializer.load(data, shuffle=shuffle))
self.ds = ds

def lmdb_props(args):
ds = dataflow.LMDBSerializer.load(args.data.format('test'),
                            shuffle=False)
ds.reset_state()
labels = []
for data in ds:
    labels.append(d[-2])
classes = np.unique(labels)

return classes
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error backtrace, as well as your pip/conda installed-package list?

Comment: thx with pip list i found out, that lmdb was installed at the wrong place